# Is there any way to force late-binding when creating views in Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-redshift, late-binding

I'm using Airflow to orchestrate ETL. Many of the tasks have `drop table` clauses that fail when a user creates a view without late-binding. Changing all tasks to `drop cascade` is not an option.

Is there any way to force late-binding? Either by user permissions or Redshift configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot force all views to use late binding at the cluster or database level. You could create a stored procedure that uses the [`v_generate_view_ddl`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_view_ddl.sql) view logic to get the DDL of all dependent views and automatically recreate them.

FWIW, I recommend not performing your ETL directly into user facing tables if you can possibly avoid it. Run the ETL against a staging schema that users cannot access and then "flip" the data into their schema(s) when it's loaded and prepped. You can use `ATLER TABLE APPEND` to quickly do the flip.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force this.

To create a late binding view, simply add

```
WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING
```

See: [CREATE VIEW - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html)